# operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'system.timespan' and 'system.datetime'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can you figure out how can I compare them both? What I mean is when I was comparing Database hours to my model hours it gives me this error :

> operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'system.timespan'
>   and 'system.datetime'

As well as the ehours

[image: Here is the screenshot]

```
var isExist = db.CRoom_Tb.Any(x => x.Rooms == b.Rooms && x.Check_In == b.Check_In && x.Hours == b.Hours && x.EHours == b.EHours);
```

My Model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:t}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime EHours { get; set; }
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:t}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Hours { get; set; }
```

My Database:

```
Hours time(7)
EHours time(7)
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is pretty explicit, and descriptive here.  You are comparing a nullable Timespan (Timespan?) to a DateTime.  And in the code for your model you posted you can clearly see it is a DateTime object.

This should be easy to work around in your code though, DateTime has a .TimeOfDay function that returns the time part of the DateTime object as a TimeSpan.

Try this:

```
var isExist = db.CRoom_Tb.Any(x => x.Rooms == b.Rooms && 
                                   x.Check_In == b.Check_In &&
                                   x.Hours == b.Hours.TimeOfDay &&
                                   x.EHours == b.EHours.TimeOfDay);
```